# Automate xmpp requests to ESL website to challenge opponents

Tags: code-golf, game

ESL gaming, where you can challenge players to play games. I've provided some steps you can take manually to challenge a player. *Note that you have to signup for an account and have to be logged in to perform these steps. (Important: you have to sign-up for the ladder before you can challenge on that ladder too. Finally some ladders requires game guid to be added, so If you don't want to get involved with that, I suggest you signup for [this ladder](http://www.esl.eu/eu/pokerth/1on1/fixed_ladder/signup/), and wait for admin verification, which should happen in a few hours, and you are good to go.)*

---

#### The challenge

**[Prerequisite]**:  Figure out the technology powering the website, specifically sending the form. (The title is a hint.)

- Automate whole process. Fewest bytes to achieve a challenge on a ladder wins.
- **[-210 bytes bonus]** Make all the optional choices configurable, including:

  - [-40 bytes] The opponent to pick.
  - [-40 bytes] The ladder to challenge on.
  - [-30 bytes] The fields of the form.
  - **[-100 bytes extra bonus]** If you have chosen the path to take the bonus, make a nice gui to get this extra bonus.

---

#### Steps

1. Go to the ladder webpage: http://www.esl.eu/eu/cod4/promod/sd/1on1/ladder/.
2. See the list of opponents, click on one (any, eg: [Hellraizer](http://www.esl.eu/eu/cod4/promod/sd/1on1/ladder/player/4044209/)).
3. On the player page: http://www.esl.eu/eu/cod4/promod/sd/1on1/ladder/player/4044209/

   Scroll down to see Leagues&Tournaments where you can challenge player on a ladder.

   [image: Click challenge on Leagues&Tournaments]
4. Click [challenge!](http://www.esl.eu/eu/cod4/promod/dm/ladder/matchsetup/challenge/4790397/) on a Ladder. (SD or DM pick any).

   It will show a form, you don't have to fill anything, just click SEND.
   [image: Just click send. No need to fill out the form.]

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! This doesn't seem to have a winning criterion, so it is off-topic for this site. Also "Figure out the technology powering the website" seems to indicate that this question is under-specified.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, I don't understand, I've given out 3 challenge problems, they can be weighted with points and highest point wins.

Comment: This seems awfully practical for a code golf puzzle.

Comment: Ok I edited, how about now, is it more fun/doable? @Compass

Comment: Since you seem to be trying, I retracted my close vote. In the future, try posting on our [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) first :) That said, I still think this is too practical to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Am I right to assume that this is your website?

Comment: No, I just play games @sudo.

Comment: Since you suggest we sign up on [PokerTH](http://www.esl.eu/eu/pokerth/1on1/fixed_ladder/signup/) and you asked a [question about developing a poker game](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/83193 "how to store game state for a multiplayer board game eg. poker"), I was suspicious.